# How compose Expression: selector + predicate?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

Assume that we have two classes

```
public class EntityA
{
    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And two expressions for selector and predicator

```
Expression<Func<EntityA, EntityB>> selector = c => c.EntityB;
Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> predicate = c => c.IsDeleted && c.Name == "AAA";
```

I need write a method that returns composed expression like a

```
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Compose<TPropType>(Expression<Func<TSource, TPropType>> selector, Expression<Func<TPropType, bool>> predicator)
{
    // Expression API ???
}
```

In my example result should be

```
Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> exp = Compose(selector, predicate);
```

what is equivalent to

```
Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> exp = c => c.EntityB.IsDeleted && c.EntityB.Name == "AAA";
```

Comment: That last `c.Name == "AAA"` should be `c.EntityB.Name == "AAA"`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Corrected.

Comment: This is such a well-asked question; it's like you're a prompt engineer travelling back in time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Compose<TSource, TPropType>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TPropType>> selector,
    Expression<Func<TPropType, bool>> predicator)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "sourceObj");
    Expression invokedSelector = Expression.Invoke(selector, new Expression[] { param });
    Expression invokedPredicate = Expression.Invoke(predicator, new[] { invokedSelector });

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(invokedPredicate, new[] { param });
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
static void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<EntityA, EntityB>> selector = c => c.EntityB;
    Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> predicate = c => c.IsDeleted && c.Name == "AAA";

    Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> exp = Compose(selector, predicate);
    System.Console.WriteLine(exp.Compile()(new EntityA()));
}
```

Comment: Note this doesn't actually work if the query needs to be mapped to a query language; the other answer works very well (speaking as someone that wasted those few minutes coz I wasn't correctly coffee'd at the time)

Answer (score 4):

Invoking these lambda expressions is certainly something you do not want to be doing.  What you should be doing is rewriting the expressions.  You'll just need a way to bind values to the lambda expressions as if you invoked them.  To do that, rewrite the bodies of the expressions replacing the parameters with the values you're binding to.  You can use this `SubstitutionVisitor` to help do that:

```
public class SubstitutionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression OldExpr { get; set; }
    public Expression NewExpr { get; set; }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return (node == OldExpr) ? NewExpr : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Given these expressions for example:

```
Expression<Func<EntityA, EntityB>> selector =
    entityA => entityA.EntityB;
Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> predicate =
    entityB => entityB.IsDeleted && entityB.Name == "AAA";
```

The goal is to effectively rewrite it so it becomes like this:

```
Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> composed =
    entity => entity.EntityB.IsDeleted && entity.EntityB.Name == "AAA";
```

```
static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Compose<TSource, TProp>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProp>> selector,
    Expression<Func<TProp, bool>> predicate)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "entity");
    var property = new SubstitutionVisitor
    {
        OldExpr = selector.Parameters.Single(),
        NewExpr = parameter,
    }.Visit(selector.Body);
    var body = new SubstitutionVisitor
    {
        OldExpr = predicate.Parameters.Single(),
        NewExpr = property,
    }.Visit(predicate.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

To understand what's going on here, here's a line-by-line explanation:

1. Create a new parameter for the new lambda we're creating.

   ```
    entity => ...
   ```
2. Given the selector, replace all instances of the original parameter `entityA` with our new parameter `entity` from the body of the lambda to obtain the property.

   ```
    entityA => entityA.EntityB
    // becomes
    entity.EntityB
   ```
3. Given the predicate, replace all instances of the original parameter `entityB` with previously obtained property `entity.EntityB` from the body of the lambda to obtain the body of our new lambda.

   ```
    entityB => entityB.IsDeleted && entityB.Name == "AAA"
    // becomes
    entity.EntityB.IsDeleted && entity.EntityB.Name == "AAA"
   ```
4. Put it all together into the new lambda.

   ```
    entity => entity.EntityB.IsDeleted && entity.EntityB.Name == "AAA"
   ```

---

F# port, in case people fin'd it more legible:

```ml
static private Compose<'T, 'I>(selector: Expression<Func<'T, 'I>>, predicate: Expression<Func<'I, bool>>) =
    let expand find replace =
        { new ExpressionVisitor() with
            override _.Visit node =
                if node = find then replace
                else base.Visit node }
    let param = Expression.Parameter(typeof<'T>, "x")
    let prop = (expand selector.Parameters[0] param).Visit(selector.Body)
    let body = (expand predicate.Parameters[0] prop).Visit(predicate.Body)
    Expression.Lambda<Func<'T, bool>>(body, param)
```

Comment: One more solution is to use LinqKit. In this case

Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> output = c => predicate.Invoke(selector.Invoke(c));

Comment: I wouldn't say so. It still compiles and invokes the expressions. If it _bound_ the arguments to the parameters of the lambda, then yes I'd consider it a solution. It's essentially a nicer way to do the other solution.  I'm not too familiar with that library but it looks like you need to `Expand()` that expression to get the results of my solution.